# Android layout preview

Tags: android, xml, preview

I am developing a tablet-only app and I put xml files for **10 inch tablets in /res/layout-sw720dp** folder.

When I preview customized xml in eclipse, I select device as "10.1in WXGA (Tablet) (1280x800: mdpi) and everything is positioned just fine (note: certain elements need to be positioned by adding some margins (in dp) ... ), **but when I run this app on samsung's galaxy tab this elements are not positioned as xml editor shows.**

What could be the problem?

Comment: What tab are you using exactly?

Comment: In your graphical layout you might missed some thing like Theme.Title bar, full screen or status bar.

Comment: I think you could provide at least screenshots of both situation. Generally, some UI elements, for example `TextView`, could have diffenret size on real devices because the size of Font itself could be a bit different (have more padding place for instance).

Comment: it's samsung's galaxy tab, not tab2. and some elements (imageviews) are on real device and simulator are positioned slightly higher (y direction) as shown in eclipse preview, so a gap i visible .

Comment: is your tablet running `Android 3.2` ? It needs update to run on `Android 3.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [link 1](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) and [link 2](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and you will get idea about how android supports multiple screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Better use wrap content or use layout_weight attribute instead of fixing the sizes, for more consistent look on all devices